Is statement in C++, i.e., instructions ends with semi-colon ';', executed as a whole in multi-thread context?
Say I have a std::atomic called num:
std::atomic<double> num{3.1415};

as C++ does not completely support arithmetic operations for atomics except for "integral types", I cannot do:
num *= 10;

Instead, I'll have to do
num.store( num.load() * 10 );  

Is it at risk of data race? e.g., after num.load() but before num.store(), is it possible that an another thread already updated the atomic?

A race condition means two threads access/modify the same variable without sequencing (e.g. so one update can be interrupted by another when partially complete).    It is possible that num will be updated after the call of num.load() and before the call of num.store() (multiplication is not an atomic operation) but that is not a race condition since the updates of num will be sequenced.   The consequence is that the update will be lost (num overwritten) by num.store().

@Peter: beg to differ... that the store and load are atomic and sequenced doesn't mean there's not a race condition.  The relative timing of read/write accesses from other threads can affect the logical correctness of use (updates to and values read from) num: that makes it a race condition.  More specifically, if another thread updates num after the "*=10" thread has done the load and before its done the store, then the other thread's update is clobbered/overwritten.  For example, two threads attempting *=10 updates could end up only increasing num by a factor of 10 instead of 100.

There's no data-race undefined behaviour, but separately-atomic load and store don't make an atomic RMW so yes multiple threads executing this code will step on each other.  (People call this a race condition or data race, although it's not what the C++ standard defines as a data race since the variable is atomic).  Anyway, whole C++ statements aren't atomic transactions!!  One statement can modify multiple separate atomic and non-atomic variables which most hardware can't do as a transaction without locking.

@TonyDelroy, When you talk to C++ people, "race condition" means something different from what it means to the rest of the world. In C++, "race condition" and "data race" both mean the same thing, and the example here doesn't have one. This program only has two possible outcomes, both of which are well defined. The final value of the variable will be that which was stored by one thread or the other. Even though you can't know which, C++ people don't say, "race condition." They only say it when the program breaks certain rules in a way that makes the outcome completely undefined.

@SolomonSlow: "when you talk to C++ people" - perhaps those you've talked to, but not the ones I've talked with.  I agree with Peter Cordes's point though contrasting C++ specific "data race" terminology with the general developer/threading notion of a "race condition".

While num.store(num.load() * 10) still has a race condition, you can use the atomic_compare_exchange to do what you want.
The big-picture idea of using compare-and-exchange (sometimes known as compare-and-swap) operations is, in pseudo-code
do {
     last-value-read = atomic-read-of-memory-location
     desired-value = last-value-read * 10
} while (atomic-compare-and-exchange(atomic-update-to=desired_value,
                                     only-if-memory-still=last-value-read));

(Some APIs, like C++s, make it easier by updating the last-value-read variable inside the compare-and-exchange operation if the memory content doesn't match the input value, so you just loop recalculating the desired-value.)
With this approach, you can implement your own more-complex atomic operations, even implement things like read-write locks where specific bits in the atomic value represent counters and boolean flags....


Is it at risk of data race?

Yes. In fact, the reason you can't do it with *= is because it might make you think that it wasn't a possible data race. By forcing you to explicitly do a load and a store, it makes it clear you are doing two operations.
Two sequential atomic operations are not as a whole atomic.

std::atomic provides compare_exchange_weak which is sufficient to implement a fetch_mul or operator* if they wanted to.  It's just inconvenient that they make you roll your own.  Or to make my point another way, if *= existed, it would be an atomic RMW.  So your first sentence seems a weird way to put it.  Perhaps they don't provide it because no real hardware has it as a single-instruction atomic, so only LL/SC machines could do it as simply as they could for fetch_add / +=.  And/or because it's more rarely needed.

It's not that it wouldn't be a "single-instruction atomic"; it's that it would be a "quite expensive atomic", requiring looping to see if nobody modified the value of the variable when you first read it.

fetch_xor, fetch_and etc. require a CAS retry loop on x86 if you use the return value.  Only fetch_sub / fetch_add can optimize to lock xadd.   To be fair, some CPUs don't have an integer multiply instruction, and a looping implementation of multiply creates a larger race window so potentially more retries.  That's probably the more likely reason for not providing operator*= / fetch_mul.

"Data race" is not the same thing as a "race condition". The former is a specific kind of UB that can happen when accessing non-atomic variables from different threads. The latter is a generic word for multithreading bugs.
Your code doesn't have data race UB. It does have a race condition (you can get a wrong number if another thread modifies the variable between the two operations).

The OP didn't ask if the program had a data race; it asked if it was "at risk" of it. Which it is.

@NicolBolas "Which it is." But it isn't? A data race by definition requires a non-atomic object to race on, but there's none. http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#def:data_race

I would like to add to the existing answers, that

Is it at risk of data race?

No, not according to C++ standard definition of "data race":
[intro.races]/21

The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

Your program is equivalent to:
auto val = num.load() * 10;
// here you could have some more statements
num.store(val);


so from the standard POV, you don't have a data race, and you don't have undefined behavior. However,

after num.load() but before num.store(), is it possible that an another thread already updated the atomic?

Absolutely yes. And you cannot be sure what will be the final value of your num after running N threads. But it's not Undefined Behavior, you just wrote a program that behaves in a non-deterministic way.

To explicitly answer one part of the question which is a common misconception:

Merely having several operations contained within the same statement does not make them execute atomically.

If it did, then you would be able to construct arbitrarily complex atomic operations, involving any number of objects (e.g. using the comma operator). But real machines have no way to actually execute such a thing. They typically provide a very limited set of lock-free atomic operations, which act only on a single object, and the atomic read-modify-write member functions of std::atomic<T> provide a way to use them.
C++ is good at exposing the capabilities of hardware to programmers in a fairly portable way, but it isn't magic and can't do things that the underlying hardware isn't already capable of doing.

Thanks for bringing up the comma separated statement scenario, I was otherwise wondering how hard it could be to make a single statement atomic.
